# XSD Choice with optional element

Tags: xsd, infopath

I have the following XSD template for the following:

```
<xsd:choice>                            
<xsd:element name="NilReport" type="ftc:CorrectableNilReport_Type">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Nil Report indicates that financial institution does not have accounts to report</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>                          
<xsd:sequence >          
    <xsd:element name="AccountReport" type="ftc:CorrectableAccountReport_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Detailed information for account report, such as account number and account balance</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="PoolReport" type="ftc:CorrectablePoolReport_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Information about the pool of account holders with similar characteristics</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>          
</xsd:sequence>
```

But the result so far doesn't go as it supposes to be.
[Unexpected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ja2E.png)

Here is my wanted result:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voKlM.png)

How could i archive the expected result ? Please advice me.

Please note that both  and  are optional in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your choice lets you pick between the NilReport element and the sequence with the other two elements.

If you want to have the two other elements as children of the "sequence" you will have to create a containing element, and you need to define them as children of that element as follows.

```
<xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="NilReport" type="ftc:CorrectableNilReport_Type">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">Nil Report indicates
                    that financial institution does not have accounts to report</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="NotNilReport">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="AccountReport" type="ftc:CorrectableAccountReport_Type"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Detailed information for account report, such
                                as account number and account balance</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="PoolReport" type="ftc:CorrectablePoolReport_Type"
                        minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:documentation>Information about the pool of account holders
                                with similar characteristics</xsd:documentation>
                        </xsd:annotation>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:choice>
```

Comment: Hi @ophychius, i'd appreciate your answer. Do we really have no other way to archive that without creating containing element?

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve, if you want an element that can contain either a NilReport or a combination of PoolReport and/or AccountReport elements than your current xsd is ok. It will not allow the combination of a NilReport and either of the other 2, while allowing 0-n AccountReports followed by 0-n PoolReports

If you want the Account- and PoolReport to be grouped together within the above mentioned element you need a choice between the NilReport and the 'NotNilReport' that contains the Account- and PoolReport elements.

Maybe try to explain exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Your above example is perfect, but it doesn't follow its default schema. So its correct xml should be:
`<ftc:NotNilReport><ftc:PoolReport><ftc:DocSpec><ftc:DocTypeIndic>FATCA1</ftc:DocTypeIndic><ftc:DocRefId>XXXX</ftc:DocRefId> <ftc:CorrMessageRefId>XXXX</ftc:CorrMessageRefId>   <ftc:CorrDocRefId>XXX</ftc:CorrDocRefId></ftc:DocSpec><ftc:AccountCount>3</ftc:AccountCount>ftc:AccountPoolReportType>FATCA201</ftc:AccountPoolReportType>
<ftc:PoolBalance currCode="AED">33</ftc:PoolBalance></ftc:PoolReport></ftc:NotNilReport>` **without <ftc:NotNilReport> tag **

Comment: Is there anyway you to do so?

Comment: What you describe is valid according to your own schema. Can you try (as part of your question, not a comment) to describe the actual problem that your run into with the xml/xsd? What xml structure do you want to describe or validate and what is going wrong?